# Why is Rob translated as 롭이 instead of 로비?

Tags: translation, names

According to [a course](https://www.memrise.com/course/2141906/korean-1/5/) at memrise.com, 저는 롭이에요 means I'm Rob (humble). I am wondering why Rob is translated as 롭이 instead of 로비. To me, the latter seems to be more natural and is easier to write.

Comment: Robby would be `로비`. But Rob is written as `롭`. So `롭이에요` == `롭`+`이에요` and `롭이` == `롭`+`이`.

Answer (score 2):

In the given Korean sentence, Rob corresponds to 롭, not 롭이.

The closest transliteration of the English name Rob /rob/ [ɹ̠ɒb] would be 롭 /rob/ [ɾop̚] according to Korean phonology and phonetics (and also the ROK government standard). 롭이/로비 would sound /robi/ [ɾobi], with a completely unnecessary [i].

The sentence "저는 롭이에요" is decomposed into

- [저](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/3ce1bf4344dc44d6b92db5f58b94ecfe): I(polite)
- [-는](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/3fd3be7d72d54db291e9d6ff06590af4): topic marker
- 롭: Rob
- [-이(다)](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/974ccf36be524c6a9bba9f4a1ed8fa6c): descriptive postposition
- [-에요](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/d952b1cdb8534024971c5aecd868b962): descriptive ending(polite)

Answer (score 1):

Someone already commented but if i expand that sentence,

it is actually

> 저 + 는 + 롭 + 이에요

So Rob is 롭 In korean.

That's how we change English sound to Korean in general.

And since you want to write something easy '롭' is best for you. :)